# Interview questions

Tags: discussion, scope

It this a good site to ask others to review my interview question practice code? Or are you trying to keep it to "real world" questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are ontopic and very welcome on Code Review SE. We already have a tag for them with 20+ questions: [interview-questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview-questions).

Please note that non-compiling and pseuode-code usually are not a problem on a whiteboard interviews but codes posted here should compile and shouldn't be pseudo-code. (Check the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) for the details.)

(Actually there are two tags, the second is the [interview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interview) but I think [it should be a synonym](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest).)

Comment: I went ahead and approved your suggested synonym

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Thank you!

Comment: I stumbled on this question because I'm concerned about limiting the effectiveness of an interview question that I was asked in future interviews. Is that not worth worrying about?